# Difference of repo sync repo init toward git clone and git pull

Tags: git, github

Based on my understanding that when I try to clone the changes of my branch I would.`repo init -u ssh://git@bitbucket.url:1234/Folder1/course.git -b my_branch -g IT`then `repo sync`.I discovered that some people also use `git clone -b my_branch ssh://git@bitbucket.url:1234/Folder1/course.git` then `git pull origin my_branch` .What is the difference between these 2 sets of command ? Both are basically the same right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's Repo is designed to manage Android codebase which is usually composed of over 400 git repos. The git repo url following -u is a git repo for Repo's  manifests only. It stores manifests that describe a snapshot of all the git repos of some Android codebase. `repo sync` then parses the manifest and clones each git repo and checkouts each revision.

The git commands are for a more general purpose. Repo commands are packaged git commands to manipulate multiple repos.